# Coding a variable n(i)=(-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,...) for a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create the tiles for a user input value for a Fibronacci number. What I have below works, but seems crude.

```
from tkinter import *
def main():
    print("This program graphically represent the Fibronacci numbers up to")
    print("the nth number requested by the user (1,1,2,3,5,8,...)")
    n = eval(input("Enter the number of the series you would like -eg n=7 for 13:"))
    a,b=1,1
    x0,y0=150,150
    canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=300, bg='white')
    canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)        
    print(a)
    print(b)
    m1=[1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1]
    m2=[-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1]
    color=["red", "blue", "green","yellow","magenta",
           "red", "blue", "green","yellow","magenta",
           "red", "blue", "green","yellow","magenta",
           "red", "blue", "green","yellow","magenta",
           "red", "blue", "green","yellow","magenta"]
    for i in range (1, n-1):

            a,b=b,a+b
            print(b)

            #m1=(-1)**i
            #m2=(-1)**(i+1)

            x1,y1=x0+m1[i-1]*b*10,y0+m2[i-1]*b*10

            canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1,dash=(4, 4),fill=color[i-1]) 
            print(x0,y0)
            print(x1,y1)

            x0,y0=x1,y1
            print(x0,y0)
    print("The ",n,"th Fibronacci number is ", b,)   
main()
```

How can the lists m1 and m2 be created inside the for loop?

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you're trying to create?

Comment: Also random tip (just because you did it 3 times): It is "Fibonacci", there is no "r".

Comment: Applying eval to user input is dangerous and should be avoided, especially in public example code.  Please change 'eval' to 'int'.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own iterator, like this:

```
$ cat t.py 
class Alternator:
    def __init__(self, first=1):
        self.previous = first
        self.current = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self): # Python 3: def __next__(self):
        self.previous, self.current = self.current, -self.previous
        return self.current
```

and then, use it like this

```
m1 = Alternator(first=-1)
m2 = Alternator(first=1)
for i in range(20):
    print "m1=%d\tm2=%d" % (m1.next(),  m2.next())
```

and the result is that `m1` and `m2` take values in the sequence you set in the lists in your example:

```
$ python t.py 
m1=1    m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=1
m1=1    m2=1
m1=1    m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=1
m1=1    m2=1
m1=1    m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=1
m1=1    m2=1
m1=1    m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=1
m1=1    m2=1
m1=1    m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=-1
m1=-1   m2=1
m1=1    m2=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing pre-computed lists of values for `m1`, `m2`, and `color`, define iterators.

```
import itertools import izip, cycle, is lice


m1s = cycle([1, 1, -1, -1])  # We don't want the first 1 ...
m1s = islice(m1s, 1, None)   # ... so we'll skip it. Think m1s = m1s[1:]
m2s = cycle([-1, -1, 1, 1])
colors = cycle(["red", "blue", "green","yellow","magenta"])

for m1, m2, color in izip(m1s, m2s, colors):
    # ...
```

`cycle` creates an iterator that returns one element at a time from its input, repeat the list as necessary. We use `islice` to start `m1s` on the second element, skipping the first 1 in `m1s`. `izip` returns an iterator of tuples, so that the first element is a tuple consisting of the first item of the three iterators, the second element the second items, etc.

This way, you don't need to store a list of all the values you'll need.

Comment: Your suggestion just results in m1=(1,-1,1,-1,...) & m2=(-1,1,-1,1,...) What I need is m1=[1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1]
    m2=[-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1]